# How to send a completly new request in javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently writing a userscript. That means, javascript is "injected" into a website the userscript specify by your browser when visiting.

Now I want to only get the last 500 bytes of e.g. this site http://www.tgchan.org/kusaba/quest/res/499039.html

Using Greasemonkey everything works fine:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Accept-Encoding": "",   
        "Range": "bytes=-500"          
    },
    url: window.location.href.match(/http:\/\/[\s\S]*\//) + 'res/'+threadid+".html",
    onload: function(responseDetails) {
        console.log(responseDetails.responseText.length);
    }
});
```

But doing this without GM_xmlhttpRequest like

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.onreadystatechange=function(){if(r.readyState==4)console.log ( r.responseText.length );}; 
r.open('GET', 'res/'+threadid+".html",true);
r.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=-500');
r.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', '');
r.send(null);
```

or with jQuery or Ajax will result in

> Accept-Encoding:        gzip, deflate

So, this header is already set and cannot be changed.

Now, as I know I can't change this header, can I do a completely new request somehow, like Greasemonkey is using? Tampermonkey for chrome and Opera fail here, too...
Or can I get the last 500 bytes even while it is gzip-encoded?

Comment: Not all servers will honor Range requests for all pages. Are you sure this one does?

Comment: @duskwuff As I said: I tried it out. I used "Live HTTP headers" and the GM_xmlhttpRequest-function is also working with Range!